# Jquery trigger change does not seem to trigger function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, triggers

I have this range slider on my webapp, the goal of my code is this:
When i slide the range slider the value of it goes into a number field using jquery, then i trigger change on this number input field, after that happens it should activate a function that is defined somewhere.

Listener for slider change (selectors have been checked on if they work and target the right elements):

```
    $('.summary').on('change', 'input[type="range"]', function(){
        console.log('confimation');
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.quantity input[type="number"]').val($(this).val()).attr('value', $(this).val());
        $(this).closest('.bundled_item_button').find('input.bundled_qty').trigger('change');
    });
```

The listener for the number field which i want to trigger with the code above (good to know here is that the console.log returns input.bundled_qty):

```
this.bind_bundled_item_event_handlers = function( bundled_item ) {
            console.log(bundled_item.$self);
            bundled_item.$self

                /**
                 * Update totals upon changing quantities.
                 */
                .on( 'input change', 'input.bundled_qty', function( event ) {
                    console.log('gevuurd');
                    var $input = $( this ),
                        qty    = parseFloat( $input.val() ),
                        min    = parseFloat( $input.attr( 'min' ) ),
                        max    = parseFloat( $input.attr( 'max' ) );

                    if ( wc_bundle_params.force_min_max_qty_input === 'yes' && 'change' === event.type ) {

                        if ( min >= 0 && ( qty < min || isNaN( qty ) ) ) {
                            qty = min;
                        }

                        if ( max > 0 && qty > max ) {
                            qty = max;
                        }

                        $input.val( qty );
                    }

                    // A zero quantity item is considered optional by NYP.
                    if( bundled_item.is_nyp() && ! bundled_item.is_optional() && min === 0 ) {
                        bundled_item.$nyp.data( 'optional_status', qty > 0 ? true : false );
                    }

                    bundled_item.update_selection_title();

                    bundle.$bundle_data.trigger( 'woocommerce-product-bundle-update', [ bundled_item ] );
                } )
}
```

When i slide the range slider it does not echo anything to the console.
The weird thing to me is that if i make a new listener in the same javascript file as the first snippit targeting the number input it does echo something to the console

```
$('.cart').on('input change', 'input.bundled_qty', function(){
        console.log('changed');
});
```

And lastly here is the HTML:

```
<div class="cart" data-title="Stokâlde fryske - 220gram" data-product_title="Stokâlde fryske - 220gram" data-visible="yes" data-optional_suffix="" data-optional="no" data-type="simple" data-bundled_item_id="4" data-custom_data="[]" data-product_id="181"
  data-bundle_id="168">
  <div class="bundled_item_wrap">
    <div class="bundled_item_cart_content">
      <div class="bundled_item_cart_details"><span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>4.75</span> <span class="bundled_item_price_quantity">each</span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="bundled_item_after_cart_details bundled_item_button">
        <div class="quantity">
          <label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_6500736040691">Stokâlde fryske - 220gram aantal</label>
          <input type="number" id="quantity_6500736040691" class="input-text qty bundled_qty text" name="bundle_quantity_4" value="2" aria-label="Productaantal" size="4" min="0" max="4" step="1" placeholder="" inputmode="numeric" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="quantity"><input type="range" min="0" max="4" name="quantityslider"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

What am i missing here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should include the relevant html as well.

Comment: @mykaf You are right, relevant HTML added

Comment: Firstly, you need a comma between `input.bundled_qty'` and `function()`.

Comment: There are no elements with class "summary." What is the context for `this.bind_bundled_item_event_handlers...`? What does `this` refer to?

Comment: There also appear to be no entities with class `has_qty_input` referred to in the code "that works".

Comment: Please see [mcve] and try to create a snippet ([edit] and click `[<>]`) that *demonstrates* the issue - it needs to be *all* the relevant code/context but *only* the relevant code/context (ie parseFloat min/max code doesn't appear to be relevant to the issue so should not be included).

Comment: **Always check your selectors** - if in doubt, check that your selector is working - ie `console.log($(this).closest('.bundled_item_button').length, $(this).closest('.bundled_item_button').find('input.bundled_qty').length)`. As well as checking that your `change` event on `summary` is firing - in the code provided it will not be, as noted above, there's no elements with `summary` so we can't confirm that `summary` is a *child* of `bundled_item_button`.

Comment: @freedomn-m Question has been updated, selectors have been checked, summary element has been removed from the code as it was not relevant.

Comment: There's still no element with class `summary` - *given the code provided* - so `$(".summary").on....` will not setup your event, so no event gets fired (**because the selector is not correct**). Changing `$(".summary")` to `$(".cart")` to match your HTML and your trigger() works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/8qdzjs7v/.

Comment: You've also not provided context of how/when(or even *if*)/what `this.bind_bundled_item_event_handlers` gets called, so we can assume it doesn't -  So it must be something to do with `this.bind_bundled_item_event_handlers` - which is needs to be detailed in the question.